# Using DataFrameWriterV2.overwrite() method to overwrite rows in a Iceberg Table

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue, apache-iceberg

I've an Iceberg Table in AWS Glue, using **pyspark** and I need, for every write of my DataFrame, to overwrite only existing rows in the table. I've discovered the `DataFrameWriterV2.overwrite()` method and I'm trying to use it as follows:

`df.sortWithinPartitions(F.to_date("ts"), "account_id").repartitionByRange(F.to_date("ts")).writeTo( my_table ).overwrite(F.col("id"))`

because my `id` column tells if a row is duplicated, and that can be overwritten in the table.

**But, I'm always getting a** `TypeError: Column is not iterable`.

I couldn't get it to work at all.
Any idea about how to overwrite a row in the table?

I'm expecting to see in the destination table all rows overwritten when the `id` value of the rows in my DataFrame already existed in the table. That to avoid duplicated rows in my destination table.
Thank you.